# How to Handle special charecters in Drools constraints

Tags: drools

when i used special charecters in Drools 6.3.0 constraints 
proposals were not coming from the kie-session  when a jar file created by "kie-maven-plugin" using RF Files?

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: Dro ols is like Java w.r.t. character handling. There are no "special" characters. - It's completely unclear what you mean.